# Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext' error

Tags: c#, .net, database, postgresql, connection

I'm trying to create the database tables using entity core frame work using
dotnet ef migrations add init  --verbose
and
dotnet ef database update
but when I'm trying to update the table I'm getting an error "Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728%22)

ApplicationDbContext

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Audit.Service.Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Audit.Service.Infrastructure.Repositories
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext

    {

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Server = localhost; Port = 5432; User Id = postgres; Password =; Database = AuditHistory; ");
        }

        public DbSet<AuditHistory> Audits => Set<AuditHistory>();

    }
}
```

I have tried like below as well. for this method also I'm getting error

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(o => o.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("auditDb"), options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure()))
```

ApplicationDbcontext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {

    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;

    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("auditDb"));
    }
    public DbSet<AuditHistory> Audits { get; set; }
}
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
 "Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
  }
 },
 "AllowedHosts": "*",
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "auditDb":"Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=;Database=AuditHistory;"

 }
 }
```

Error

```
    System.ArgumentException: Host can't be null
     at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.PostProcessAndValidate()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.SetupDataSource()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.CloneWith(String connectionString)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlRelationalConnection.CloneWith(String connectionString)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Host can't be null
```

Comment: How did you attempt to create the tables?

Comment: @DavidG tried  with cmd dotnet ef migrations add init  --verbose
and
dotnet ef database update

Comment: You are using Entity where there is a mapping between the c# classes and the database tables/fields.  You need to update the mapping.  You cannot just add a table to the database without the mapping getting update.  The right thing to do is to use Migration Update which modifies the mapping.  Migration Update takes the c# classes and update the mapping and the database to match the classes.

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in your solution? Also, please ignore jdweng, they have no idea what they are talking about.

Comment: @jdweng I'm able to create the migration snapshots but table is not creating in the database.

Comment: @DavidG no I only have this project alone.I'm following domain driven architecture.all the projects are linked to same only.

Comment: One thing I notice here, though not sure if it is the issue, you use `GetConnectionString("AuditHistory")` but the connection string in your settings is actually called `auditDb`

Comment: @DavidG sorry no that's not the issue  I have entered it wrongly here.

Comment: Either you are getting an unreported exception or the connection string is wrong and you are updating a different database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My The Entity Framework tools version is '7.0.2' is older than that of the runtime '7.0.3'. I Updated the tools for the latest. Then it got fixed